# ZF2AuthAcl Module doesnt work out of the box

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I picked up this ZF2AuthAcl module to make my life easier. For some reason it does not work out of the box. As soon as i activate it in Zend2 Application.config it takes over the whole site. Meaning it goes straight to login on any page i have. There is a "white list" and i tried to add pages to this in an array and it does not seem to work. I will show the Acl page that it has with the "white list" maybe i did not add them correctly or there is a better way. It is data driven also. Has anyone used this with success or know about it?

The author is the one who told me it probably has to do with the white list.

The area that i added to looked like this:

```
    public function initAcl()
    {
    $this->roles = $this->_getAllRoles();
    $this->resources = $this->_getAllResources();
    $this->rolePermission = $this->_getRolePermissions();
    // we are not putting these resource & permission in table bcz it is
    // common to all user
    $this->commonPermission = array(
        'ZF2AuthAcl\Controller\Index' => array(
            'logout',
            'index'                
        ),
    );
    $this->_addRoles()
        ->_addResources()
        ->_addRoleResources();
}
```

This is the whole thing with parts i added.

```
namespace ZF2AuthAcl\Utility;

use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl as ZendAcl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource as Resource;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Acl extends ZendAcl implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

const DEFAULT_ROLE = 'guest';

protected $_roleTableObject;

protected $serviceLocator;

protected $roles;

protected $permissions;

protected $resources;

protected $rolePermission;

protected $commonPermission;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;

    return $this;
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}

public function initAcl()
{
    $this->roles = $this->_getAllRoles();
    $this->resources = $this->_getAllResources();
    $this->rolePermission = $this->_getRolePermissions();
    // we are not putting these resource & permission in table bcz it is
    // common to all user
    $this->commonPermission = array(
        'ZF2AuthAcl\Controller\Index' => array(
            'logout',
            'index'                
        ),
        'Frontend\Controller\Index' => array(
            'index'                
        ),
        'Blog\Controller\Blog' => array(
            'blog',
            'list',
            'view',
            'UsMap',
            'maps'                
        )
    );
    $this->_addRoles()
        ->_addResources()
        ->_addRoleResources();
}

public function isAccessAllowed($role, $resource, $permission)
{
    if (! $this->hasResource($resource)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected function _addRoles()
{
    $this->addRole(new Role(self::DEFAULT_ROLE));

    if (! empty($this->roles)) {
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            $roleName = $role['role_name'];
            if (! $this->hasRole($roleName)) {
                $this->addRole(new Role($roleName), self::DEFAULT_ROLE);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _addResources()
{
    if (! empty($this->resources)) {
        foreach ($this->resources as $resource) {
            if (! $this->hasResource($resource['resource_name'])) {
                $this->addResource(new Resource($resource['resource_name']));
            }
        }
    }

    // add common resources
    if (! empty($this->commonPermission)) {
        foreach ($this->commonPermission as $resource => $permissions) {
            if (! $this->hasResource($resource)) {
                $this->addResource(new Resource($resource));
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function _addRoleResources()
{
    // allow common resource/permission to guest user
    if (! empty($this->commonPermission)) {
        foreach ($this->commonPermission as $resource => $permissions) {
            foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                $this->allow(self::DEFAULT_ROLE, $resource, $permission);
            }
        }
    }

    if (! empty($this->rolePermission)) {
        foreach ($this->rolePermission as $rolePermissions) {
            $this->allow($rolePermissions['role_name'], $rolePermissions['resource_name'], $rolePermissions['permission_name']);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function _getAllRoles()
{
    $roleTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("RoleTable");
    return $roleTable->getUserRoles();
}

protected function _getAllResources()
{
    $resourceTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("ResourceTable");
    return $resourceTable->getAllResources();
}

protected function _getRolePermissions()
{
    $rolePermissionTable =   $this->getServiceLocator()->get("RolePermissionTable");
    return $rolePermissionTable->getRolePermissions();
}

private function debugAcl($role, $resource, $permission)
{
    echo 'Role:-' . $role . '==>' . $resource . '\\' . $permission .  '<br/>';
 }
}
```

06/10/2016 Additional information
I have also found that this ACL page is not in any of the pages in the module. The functions are not called out anywhere in any page nor is it "use" on any page. So how is it supposed to work?

Update 06/10/2017 - Area that has been fixed.

I have found where this is used in the module.php there is a whitelist that the pages have to be added too. Below is where you add them.

```
$whiteList = array(
        'Frontend\Controller\Index-index',
        *Add whatever modules/controller/action you do not want included*
        'ZF2AuthAcl\Controller\Index-index',
        'ZF2AuthAcl\Controller\Index-logout'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Above is the conclusion of my issue. I stumbled upon it. I did not look in the module.php file. That is where the answer was.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general implementation of Zend ACL. I followed this one. If you wish you can follow this one too.

Create a file named `module.acl.php` in the `config/` folder of your module. This file contains configuration for roles and permissions. Modify this script as you need.

ModuleName/config/module.acl.php

```
return array(
    'roles' => array(
        'guest',
        'member'
    ),
    'permissions' => array( 
        'guest' => array(
            // Names of routes for guest role
            'users-signup',
            'users-login'
        ),
        'member' => array(
            // Names of routes for member role
            // Add more here if you need
            'users-logout'
        )
    )
);
```

You need to import the following three classes and define and initialize some methods in the `Module.php`.

ModuleName/Module.php

```
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource;

// Optional; use this for authentication
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
```

Now lets create methods that will deploy ACL and check roles and permissions.

Module::initAcl()

```
public function initAcl(MvcEvent $e)
{

    // Set the ACL
    if ($e->getViewModel()->acl == null) {
        $acl = new Acl();
    } else {
        $acl = $e->getViewModel()->acl;
    }

    // Get the roles and permissions configuration
    // You may fetch configuration from database instead.
    $aclConfig = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.acl.php';

    // Set roles
    foreach ($aclConfig['roles'] as $role) {
        if (!$acl->hasRole($role)) {
            $role = new GenericRole($role);
            $acl->addRole($role);
        } else {
            $role = $acl->getRole($role);
        }

        // Set resources
        if (array_key_exists($role->getRoleId(), $aclConfig['permissions'])) {
            foreach ($aclConfig['permissions'][$role->getRoleId()] as $resource) {
                if (!$acl->hasResource($resource)) {
                    $acl->addResource(new GenericResource($resource));
                }

                // Add role to a specific resource
                $acl->allow($role, $resource);
            }
        }
    }

    // Assign the fully prepared ACL object    
    $e->getViewModel()->acl = $acl;
}
```

Module::checkAcl()

```
public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {

    // Get the route
    $route = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();

    // Use this if you have authentication set
    // Otherwise, take this off 
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();

    // Set role as you need  
    $userRole = 'guest';

    // Use this if you have authentication set
    // Otherwise, take this off  
    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $userRole = 'member';
        $loggedInUser = $auth->getIdentity();
        $e->getViewModel()->loggedInUser = $loggedInUser;
    }

    // Check if the resource has right permission 
    if (!$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();

        // Redirect to specific route
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/404');
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now call those above methods on the `onBootstrap()` method in your `Module.php`. Initialize `Module::initAcl()` and check resource permission by adding `Module::checkAcl()` to the `route` event.

Module::onBootstrap()

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{   
    $this->initAcl($e);
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach('route', array($this, 'checkAcl'));
}
```

Let us know it helps you or not!